# Handling assignment to undefined index and E_NOTICE

Tags: php, error-handling

> Looks like a lot of people did not understand the question, **the notice
>   I am getting is not about $fromdatabase, it's about $data[$key]**

For I can see in the development environment what I am getting as $fromDatabase[$key], and the error message is for the line : $data [$key] = $this->getSomeValue ($value);

> **Even if I do $data ['mykey'] I get the message undefined index mykey**

I have a situation where I need to assign some value to an undefined index of an associative array. Something like this:

```
$data = array (  );

foreach ( $something as $key => $value)
{
    /** If I do this then there is no notice **/
    $data['body'][$key] = NULL;

    foreach ( $fromDatabase as $xyz)
    {
        $data['body'][$key] = $this->getSomeValue ($xyz);
    }
}
```

`$fromDatabase` is not known and `$key` can not be predicted beforehand, all of them are dynamic.

**How do I handle the E_NOTICE (undefined index) in this situation?**

> E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized
>   variables, however not in the case of appending elements to the
>   uninitialized array. isset() language construct can be used to detect
>   if a variable has been already initialized.

PHP Manual says that but why am I getting the error while appending elements to the uninitialized array ?

Comment: your missing the `$` on `key` ... `$data[$key] = $this->getSomeValue($value);`

Comment: check if the variable is set before looping over it?

Comment: I had a feeling that missing `$` was a typo. Anyway, you've been given an answer. See if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: what about a ternary operator?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it was a typo.

Comment: @StudentX Yes, my *Spidey sense* was tingling earlier. That's why I was waiting this one out. So... ternary operator? Is that an option here? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don;t see how that's going to help

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure `$fromDatabase` exists and is an array, the rest will be OK.

`$data[$key]` will be created if it doesn't exist and `$key` and `$value` will be set automatically.

```
$data = array (  );

if (isset($fromDatabase) && is_array($fromDatabase))
    foreach ( $fromDatabase as $key => $value )
    {
        $data[$key] = $this->getSomeValue ($value); // You made a typo "key" => "$key"
    }
```

---

EDIT : I can't reproduce your error

```
$fromDatabase = ['test' => 1, 42 => 'some strange value'];

$data = array (  );
foreach ( $fromDatabase as $key => $value )
{
    $data[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($data);
```

Outputs (for me) :

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1
    [42] => some strange value
)
```

---

RE-EDIT :

```
$data = array (  );
```

change it to

```
$data = array('body' => array());
```

Comment: That's what is happening, $fromDatabase exist and is an array. Problem is with this line `$data[$key] = $this->getSomeValue ($value);` here I get the message *Undefined index $key* where $key is the actual value which I can check in the development environment.

Comment: I have updated the code. It's more like what I am doing. Please have a look.